# Order grouped scatterplot by mean

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a `geom_point` for several groups (`Loc`) and want in addition a line that indicates the mean of the points for each group. The groups should be ordered based on the mean of the `Size` for each group. I am trying to do this by `reorder(Loc, Size.Mean)` but it does not reorder.

```
  ggplot(data,aes(Loc,Size,color=Loc)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(data %>% 
               group_by(Loc) %>% 
               summarise(Size.Mean = mean(Size)),
             mapping = aes(y = Size.Mean, x = reorder(Loc, Size.Mean)),
             color = "black", shape = '-') +
  theme_pubr(base_size=8) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans="log10") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,hjust = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: The problem is that the x aesthetic is defined twice once unordered, once ordered, but the first seems to have control. I would prepare the data beforehand. Adding some data (or editing the code to use an existing dataset) would help people answer your question.

Comment: if I plot geom_point() after the mean then it works. But the mean is then hidden behind the points. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot orders discrete x ticks according to their level if the variable is a factor:

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris_means <-
  iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  arrange(-mean)

iris %>%
  mutate(Species = Species %>% factor(levels = iris_means$Species)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_crossbar(data = iris_means, mapping = aes(y = mean, ymin = mean, ymax = mean), color = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>